# Display UIPickerView when UITextField is selected

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uipickerview

Does anyone have a basic example to display a UIPickerView when a UITextField was selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was implement touchesEnded event. If that event occurs in my UITextField parameters then I either hide or show the UIPickerView

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.textField frame], [touch locationInView:self.view]))
    {
        //Want to show or hide UIPickerView
        if(pickerView)
        {
            submitButton.hidden = !submitButton.hidden;
            pickerView.hidden = !pickerView.hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best place to do so would be in the NSTextField Delegate method:

`- (BOOL)textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)textObject`

Override the method to return NO and instead evoke the picker view. Returning NO will prevent the keyboard from appearing.

Comment: I think this should be:    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Comment: You're correct. I got the wrong API.

Answer (score 0):

http://tmblr.co/ZjkSZteCOUBS

I have the code and everything laid out in my blog to do this exactly. But below, I have the basic concept laid out.

Basically the solution involves an opensource project called ActionSheetPicker on github, and implementing the function `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` on the `UITextFieldDelegate`. You can dismiss the keyboard there and provide a UIPickerView instead. The basic code is listed here:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // We are now showing the UIPickerViewer instead

    // Close the keypad if it is showing
    [self.superview endEditing:YES];

    // Function to show the picker view
    [self showPickerViewer :array :pickerTitle];

    // Return no so that no cursor is shown in the text box
    return  NO;
}
```

**EDIT** I know this question was asked a while ago, but felt it was necessary to provide a more recent solution.

Comment: Was in the process of updating the answer when you commented :)